# Unnecessary empty space below search results using UISearch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have tab in my app, where user can perform search. After user type keywords and tableView populated with results, there a lot of empty rows. I already "clean" unnecessary rows (turned it to `[UIColor clearColor]`), but now i got an empty space, problem wasn't solved. What i want is, just a table populated with search results, no empty space, no rows (it perfectly fine if there is blank space, when there is only several results on a table. But i got this "empty" space when there is many results, and i have to scroll down to see all of them. In that case, i didn't want that anything appears after last cell). There is a code, i use to create UISearch and tableView, it pretty straightforward:

For UITableView:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSLog(@"number of rows is ? %d", self.filteredArray.count);
    return [self.filteredArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSString *_cellText = self.filteredArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = _cellText;

    return cell;
}
```

For UISearch:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    self.filteredArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    self.searchResults = [NSArray new];
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];
    self.searchResults = [self._placeOfObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
    NSLog(@" metod called ");
    NSLog(@"searchResults is %@", self.searchResults);
    //    if (self.searchResults){
    //    _filteredName = ((placeHolder *)(self.searchResults)).name;
    //    NSLog(@"HOLY Grale %@", _filteredName);
    //    }
    //    NSLog(@" What user search is %@", ((placeHolder *)(self.searchResults.name));
    if (self.searchResults.count > 0){
        // _filteredName = ((placeHolder *)(self.searchResults[0])).name;
        for (int i=0; i<[self.searchResults count]; i++) {
            NSLog(@" counto %d", [self.searchResults count]);
            _filteredName = ((PlaceHolder *)(self.searchResults[i])).name;
            [self.filteredArray addObject:_filteredName];
        }
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"array is empty");
    }
    NSLog(@"HOLY WATER %@", _filteredName );
    NSLog(@" %@ holy array", self.filteredArray);
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    // Tells the table data source to reload when text changes
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:
     [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption {
    // Tells the table data source to reload when scope bar selection changes
    [self filterContentForSearchText:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text scope:
     [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:searchOption]];
    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}

- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller willShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
{
    UIView *footer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 1)];
    footer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [tableView setTableFooterView:footer];
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is the empty space between the search bar and the table? If so, you need to adjust the positions of these two UI components.

Comment: it is below last cell, that hold data..

Comment: I guess you did not specify the dimension of the table properly or you put those components on `UIScrollView` which was set with larger than screen dimension. But a screenshot might be easier to see the issue.

Comment: Or you put an extra table cell accidentally.

Comment: Problem solved, thank you Dino Tw, you was right (i didn't set tableView properly)